# why click method didn't take effect , but ActionChains works fine?

Tags: selenium

## case description

- http://sahitest.com/demo/php/fileUpload.htm
- click the first button "file",click it
- ![[Pasted image 20220815111354.png]]

## code example

```py
from selenium import webdriver  

driver = webdriver.Chrome()  
driver.get('http://sahitest.com/demo/php/fileUpload.htm')  

driver.find_element('id','file').click()
```

- error track

```
D:\Python39\python.exe D:/pythonProject/deom1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pythonProject\deom1.py", line 8, in <module>
    driver.find_element('id','file').click()
  File "D:\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 88, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "D:\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 396, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "D:\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 435, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=104.0.5112.81)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x004F5FD3+2187219]
    Ordinal0 [0x0048E6D1+1763025]
    Ordinal0 [0x003A3D40+802112]
    Ordinal0 [0x003C9171+954737]
    Ordinal0 [0x003ECB8C+1100684]
    Ordinal0 [0x003C8394+951188]
    Ordinal0 [0x003ECDA4+1101220]
    Ordinal0 [0x003FCFC2+1167298]
    Ordinal0 [0x003EC9A6+1100198]
    Ordinal0 [0x003C6F80+946048]
    Ordinal0 [0x003C7E76+949878]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x007990C2+2721218]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0078AAF0+2662384]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0058137A+526458]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00580416+522518]
    Ordinal0 [0x00494EAB+1789611]
    Ordinal0 [0x004997A8+1808296]
    Ordinal0 [0x00499895+1808533]
    Ordinal0 [0x004A26C1+1844929]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7635FA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x773A7A9E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x773A7A6E+238]
```

## fix code

```py
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains  
  
driver = webdriver.Chrome()  
driver.get('http://sahitest.com/demo/php/fileUpload.htm')  
ele_fie = driver.find_element('id','file')  
ActionChains(driver).click(ele_fie).perform()
```

## why

- i don't know how to explain this issue. who can tell me, thanks a lot.
- 

Answer (score 0):

In the DOM I see, the `input` element has attribute `type=file`, which means it is a file upload dialog that is related to OS and Selenium cannot perform operations on this one directly. Hence ActionChains.

[image: DOM Snippet]

Comment: thank you ! i am a new guy, so i can't vote for u, just comment for this.